# Disable jumping to top after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to scroll down after load with:

```
$(document).on('pageshow', function(){
        setInterval(function() {
            $.mobile.silentScroll($("#commentTop").offset().top);
        },1000);
    }
});
```

but my page have lot of image and when loading of images completed, jqm automatically jump to top of the page. how can I solve it?

Comment: i guess you have added code to jump to top of the page on pageshow. Thats why after all images are loaded on pageshow event the page tends to scroll to top due to code "$.mobile.silentScroll"

Comment: didn't found anything related to scrolling/moving in code.

Comment: I'm not sure about your requirement, Are you trying to make the page scroll down to some extend after the page is been completely loaded ?

Comment: you cant prevent JQM from jumping to page top after loading all contents, that's why `$.mobile.silentScroll()` is specifically made for JQM. Your code above should work.

Comment: @AshisKumar yes. to a top of a div. id: #commentTop

Comment: @Omar that work in mobile but not in pc browser like ff

Answer (score 3):

what I finally did was detecting PC/Mobile devices using server-side script and send out this script for pc instead:

```
window.onload = function(){
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#commentTop").offset().top
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try using the `pageload` event rather than `pageshow`. `pageshow` will be triggered as soon as the transition get finished, but the `pageload` will be triggered once the page is completely loaded.

And secondly, using this we don't need to set the interval of running the code after a while. so just you can use the below code.

```
$(document).on('pageload', function(){
    $.mobile.silentScroll($("#commentTop").offset().top);
});
```

Hope this helps you.